# creating a read/write document in memory stream

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, memorystream

I'm creating an excel doc using npoi. Using aspnet mvc's fileContentResult the output xls doc is readonly. When writing a file to stream is it possible to ensure the file has read/write capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably fileContentResult has the file stored at some temporary location. If it let you write to it, your changes would eventually get lost.

Can you just copy it to a location of your choice and then make changes to it there?